Prove $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i=2^{n+1}-1$ using WOP
So I defined my predicate $P(n)$ according to the theorem, and then I said there there exists an integer $n\ge0$ such that $P(n)$ is false. And I let $C$ be the set of all such $n$. And by WOP, there is a least element m (blah blah blah).
I then prove a few base cases and say now I'm trying to prove that $P(m-1)$ is also true, which would be a contradiction that m is the least element in $C$.
But I'm stuck on how to get $P(m-1)$ to look like $2^{n+1}-1$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You mean you're trying to show $P(m-1)$ is also false. Usually it's done by contraposition: If $P(m-1)$ is true, then $P(m)$ is true.

@user469053 I'm actually getting confused but I'm pretty sure I need to prove that P(m)  is true, which implies that m doesn't belong in C, which is a contradiction to my supposition of m is the least element of C, so C is therefore empty

Yes, that would be doing what I said by contraposition: With the base case out of the way, you want to either show that if $P(m-1)$ is true, then $P(m)$ is also true, or show that if $P(m)$ is false, then $P(m-1)$ is also false. These two things are contrapositives of each other, and are therefore equivalent. In neither case would it make sense to say that you want to prove $P(m-1)$ is "also true". One assume it as a hypothesis, and the contrapositive assume $P(m)$ is false, so the "also" in "also true" doesn't make sense.

As you've said, we assume $C\neq\varnothing$ and let $m=\min C$ (exists because $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered). Consider the cases $m=0$ and $m>0$. $m=0$ you can reach a contradiction by direct checking. For the case $m>0$, by definition of $C$ and the fact that $m\in C$, you've assumed $P(m)$ is false. So you can reach a contradiction by showing that $P(m-1)$ is also false, contradicting the minimality of $m$ in $C$. So, by the setup of the problem, you're left with a situation where $m>0$, $P(m)$ is false, and $P(m-1)$ is true. In order to reach a contradiction, you can either show that, for $m>0$,

if $P(m)$ is false, $P(m-1)$ is also false, or
if $P(m-1)$ is true, $P(m)$ is also true.

It's usually more straighforward to do the latter. Write $$\sum_{i=0}^m 2^i = 2^m+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i,$$ use the hypothesis that $P(m-1)$ is true to rewrite $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i$, and see where you get.

Thank you! I am doing the latter, but I can only get it to looking like 2^(m+1). I don't know where I'm going wrong on the right hand side

If $P(m-1)$ is true, $$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i=2^m-1.$$ So $$\sum_{i=0}^m 2^i=2^m+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i=2^m+2^m-1=2\cdot 2^m-1=2^{m+1}-1.$$
